# Sending XML response from MVC Rest API

Tags: .net, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, rest

I am trying to implement an MVC Rest API service that returns XML.

The code is somewhat like this:

```
public IEnumerable<XDocument> getXml(...)
        {
            XDocument responseXml = MakeHttpRequestAndGetResponseXML(...);
            return responseXml;
        }
```

But of course this won't work, it's just my attempt which failed. When I have an XML response in `XDocument` object, how can I return it as valid XML through my web service?

Answer (score 0):

What I've generally done in the past for this is create DTO's to represent your XML and give your DTO properties serialization attributes to describe the XML:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Service", Namespace = "")]
public class ServiceApiDTO
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 0, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 2, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Order = 3, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public DepartmentApiDTO Department { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Order = 4, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string SLA { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Order = 5, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Cost { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 6, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public ServiceStatusApiDTO CurrentStatus { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 7, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public UserApiDTO CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

and then create a WebApiController to expose these DTO's via HttpGet:

```
public class ServicesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IServiceService _serviceService;

    public ServicesController(IServiceService serviceService)
    {
        _serviceService = serviceService;
    }

    //
    // GET: /api/Services/Service.{ext}/{url}

    [HttpGet]
    public ServiceApiDTO Service(string url)
    {
        var service = _serviceService.GetServiceByUrl(url);

        if (service == null)
        {
            var error = new HttpError(String.Format("No service found with URL = '{0}'", url));

            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, error));
        }

        var serviceDTO = Mapper.Map<Service, ServiceApiDTO>(service);

        return serviceDTO;
    }
}
```

and then tell my WebApiConfig to handle Xml and Json extensions:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}.{ext}",
            defaults: new { ext = "xml|json" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApiServiceUrl",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}.{ext}/{url}",
            defaults: new { url = RouteParameter.Optional, ext = "xml|json" }
        );

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        var xmlFormatter = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter;

        jsonFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("json", "application/json");
        xmlFormatter.AddUriPathExtensionMapping("xml", "text/xml");
    }
}
```

Once you're all set, you can access your API like `http://localhost/api/Services/Service.xml/urlParameter` for response as XML or `http://localhost/api/Services/Service.json/urlParameter` for response as JSON.

This example is generally copy/pasted from one of my applications, but hopefully you can get the idea.

Just FYI, some of the technologies used here are AutoMapper to map from Domain Entity to DTO, and CastleWindsor for Dependency Injection of services into WebApiController.